# How to collapse the blank space when there is no Ad delivered

Tags: javascript, amp-html

The problem happens in AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) page.

Question:

Since I must state a width and height in AMP, I can't collapse the blank space where there is no ad in return.

***I tried with:***

- Fallback `div` - **not working**
- Tried to put a passback with a script which adds a `class` to the `div` in order to `display:none` it is **not working**, the javascript won't work
- Tried to state a variable as passback and let the publisher state this class - **not working**.

So, How can I make the `amp-ad` collapse?